# Data integrity in concurrency environment

Tags: concurrency, transactions, integrity

We know that DBMS harness many technique to ensure the data integrity and satisfying the ACID properties when there are many transactions running simultaneously in a concurrency environment. Apart from setting Isolation Level, what other means taken by DBMS to ensure data integrity? what is the relationship between these technique? Could you please give me an detail explanation?

Comment: Can you clarify your question a bit? What additional means do you need to be taken? What else is needed apart from correct transaction handling? Or you mean physical data integrity in case, for example, server power failure?

Comment: Put it simple,as a Java programmer What factors should i concern to ensure that database manipulation isn't breaching Data Integrity?

Comment: I have found a good resource from oracle reference site Myself.
http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10713/consist.htm#BABEAFAH

Comment: Would like to help, but I think you need to break this question up into more specific, targeted questions.  As it is, it's overly broad.